# How to access ZeppelinContext in sql interpreter

Tags: apache-zeppelin, spark-notebook

I am writing a Zeppelin notebook that has two paragraphs. The first paragraph is a scala notebook that defines some default values to be used in later notebooks. For eg In the first paragraph if I define

```
%scala
var table_name = "my_table"
```

How can this be used in the later %sql paragraphs eg:

```
%sql
select count(*) from <how to get value of table_name>
```

I can put the values in the ZepplinContext using z.put() but how will I access the same in the sql paragraphs?

Answer (score 0):

I hope ZeppelinContext will be available in version 0.8.

https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/pull/2903 - "[ZEPPELIN-3377] Passing Z variables to JDBC interpreter"